# How to create a vertical indented menu?

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu

I've been asked to create a sub-navigation page which would list all the links which are in a products page sections menu. The display needs to look like this:

```
Product Section 1
     sub-1
     sub-2
     sub-3
Product Section 2
     sub-1
     sub-2
     sub-3
```

Each item above needs to be clickable to go to those sections just like the regular drop-down menu does.

Is there a vertical menu module that does this? Or one that a new overlay or template written for it would accomplish this?

Comment: Could you explain how the core Joomla menu module doesn’t fulfil your requirements? I’m a bit fuzzy on what you’re attempting.

Comment: There is a lot of Vertikal Menu extensions on JED

Comment: @jamesgarrett I'm using a RSJOOMLA RSKALA! template, and I don't see a way to do a vertical menu like the above. This is for sub-navigation on a page.

Comment: I'll ask my question a different way. If you add a menu module (the joomla code menu) to a sidebar position in your template and set the start level to 2, in what way does it not satisfy your requirement?

Comment: @jamesgarrett When I have added menus, such as in the bottom, it creates it horizontal. Where I need this is in the middle in a position called inner-before content. Are you saying Joomla looks at the module position to select horizontal or vertical automatically? If so, looks like I'm going to learn something new here. And how would I override the template for this to have the layout indented like in my example?

Comment: I think it is getting clearer. Firstly, a horizontal and vertical menu are generally the same HTML - only the css and js is different. It sounds like the rskala template is applying css to make any menu horizontal. If this is the case and you are unable to sufficiently override the template’s menu styling with your own custom css, then I think the next step would be to post on the rsjoomla template forum if you haven’t already.